Android - Set TalkBack accessibility focus back to a specific view
When TalkBack is enabled, is there any way to set the accessibility focus back to a specific view after navigate out and back to the page?
For instance, when I click ButtonA in PageA and using navigationController to navigate to the PageB, and then return back to the PageA. the talkback focus do not return to the ButtonA.

I think you're going to have to force focus

The ideal scenario is if user navigate to next screen and back to previous screen focus will be on the same view but this behavior may vary device to device coz every 2nd device has their own os layer,
you can still send the accessibility focus to the view using view.sendAccessibilityEvent(), however sending accessibility event forcefully is not a good practice.
